# LinearLayoutManager(this) in Fragment Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, linearlayoutmanager

I'm learning `Kotlin` in Adroid Studio and recently I have stuck on `RecyclerView`.

The problem is that I'm not able to go forward due to error showing on `LinearLayoutManager(this)`.

[image]

My little code looks like:

```
    package com.store.example
    
    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_store.*
    
    class StoreFragment : Fragment() {
    
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
            // call recyclerView this id (fragment_store)
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        }
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store, container, false)
        }
    }
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StoreFragment">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/card_view_store" />

</FrameLayout>
```

`LinearLayoutManager(this)` is underlined and tells me that:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is StoreFragment but Context! was expected

I'm not a advanced programist, rather a newbie and I've been trying to fix this remark but at this moment its beyond my skills.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why did you think this would work in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead,

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
```

or

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
```

***activity*** returns fragment`s host activity whereas ***requireContext()*** returns the context of the fragment`s hosting activity.

Answer (score 2):

Use `requireContext()` you can get the fragment's hosting activity.

So you can try this:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the `Fragment` (`StoreFragment` to be precise), but the constructor for `LinearLayoutManager` needs a reference to an instance of `Context`.

You have a number of different ways to get a reference to a `Context`.

- `this.context` will return the context property of the fragment. Can omit `this.` and just use `context` to do the same thing.
- `view.context` will return the context property of the view argument.
- `requireActivity()` will return the activity that controls the fragment which can also be used as an instance of Context.

```kotlin
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
         // call recyclerView this id (fragment_store)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answers you've been given, `Context` parameters show up *a lot* in Android, so you need to know how to be able to get one. An `Activity` **is** a `Context`, which is why if your code were in an Activity, you could pass `this`.

But you're in a `Fragment`, which isn't a subclass of `Context`, so `this` won't work! But `Fragment`s **do** have *access* to a `Context` - either through `getContext` (or in Kotlin, the `context` property equivalent) or `requireContext`.

`getContext` returns null if you don't have one yet, meaning you have to handle that nullability. `requireContext` throws an exception if you don't have access to one, so it doesn't need to be nullable, and this is the one you're supposed to use. So long as you call `requireContext` in `onCreate` or later, [the Fragment will have been attached to its context](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#fragment_created) and it's safe to use.